# how to customize UICollectionView Layout at runtime?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I made my collection view stacked layout based this tutorial.[image] `http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial`

Now i want to implement, when i tap a stack and have it expand out into a more detailed view for that album ( each image should visible as separate cell) as well the rest of the section should move according to the number of cell in the tapped section.  How can i achieve this.

Kindly help me. thanks in advance......

Comment: For that u need to go for custom collectionlayout, create your own layout by subclassing collectionviewlayout.

Comment: thats already i done with the help of the tutorial which is mentioned in my question. but now i need to implement the which is explained in question. just give solution for that...

Comment: So the way to create this stack layout(customised) similarly u need to create custom layout for your detailed view. Thats it !

Comment: that i know, but can u provide the code for detailed layout, becz i tried lot but till its not giving proper solution for me....

Comment: I have not gone into custom layout of collection view so sorry on that part but as u said that you have gone through the tutorial then you must have learnt customisation a bit so good luck with that.

Comment: If I came across anything would let u know...!

Comment: @walle84, thank you, i tried when i tap a section, counting number of cell in that section, then changing the frame center of that section variously so that it will visible as detailed, rest of the section cell's frame center i didn't changed. its working fine. the issue is position for the section is not moved.

Comment: For this I need to look into your code so if possible share your code.

Comment: yeah okay @walle84, i cant post here, there is nay other way to send to u.....

Comment: upload it on github and share the link..will download and go through it

Comment: just positing the frame, i was playing with center, better i could done with the frame.